# htaccess handler

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have strange problem that need help. It is about rewrite using apache.

Here my .htaccess content file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks


 ## This is an example .htaccess-file
 ## To get everything automatically parsed, the following line is needed
 #set link auto on

 ##From now on, every RewriteRule gets recognised.
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule captcha(\.html){0,1}$  captcha.php [QSA,L]
 RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-s
 RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
 Rewriterule (.*) handler.php

 ##You can also change the text before the real link by the following line
```

With this rule, I am hoping that all request except there is exists in file or directory will be directed to my custom handler: handler.php.

Everyting just fine as expected but this case not:

```
http://../test/form_login/query=%2Ftest%2Findex.php%3Fpage%3Dform&
```

Root url: /test/,
form_login is not file or directory
index.php is exists in the root.

Apache response with : 404 Page Not Found

Thanks for any of your help.

Regards,
Steve

Comment: Your formatting got busted in the post. Please try to format the sample `.htaccess` properly so that we can see it.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could list a bunch of example URLs, alongside their actual rewrite behaviour and the behaviour that you desire. Then we can better understand what it is that you are trying to do.

Comment: Apache response with: Not Found (404)

Comment: Hi Tomalak, How I dont know to make good format. At the time I am write, the preview so good format. please tell me how?

Comment: Hi, No code available on both handler.php and index.php than just echoing my debug message: echo 'debug'; an then exit. Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are rewriteing to the same non-existant directory...

```
Rewriterule (.*) handler.php
```

So if i go to yourdomain.com/no/directory/exists/

it redirects me to yourdomain.com/no/directory/exists/handler.php

So no file/directory

use a rewrite base or use

```
Rewriterule (.*) /handler.php
```

if handler.php exists at yourdomain.com/handler.php

and you might want to add a QSA on to append the variables...

```
Rewriterule (.*) /handler.php [R,QSA,L]
```

** also added the R flag to update/show the reidrect url in the browsers as well as the L flag for last rule...

Comment: Hi, thanks. But the problem is not on the .htaccess. If i do request as per your example if ok. Problem is in the query http://../test/form_login/query=%2Ftest%2Findex.php%3Fpage%3Dform&. Thanks again.